# Do Control System questions belong in EE.SE?

Tags: discussion

Control theory is part of many undergraduate electrical engineering courses. Are questions regarding the control theory portion of a control system relevant here? What I mean is not the electronics aspect of it, but rather questions regarding how to improve transient response, disturbance, etc.

If it's not, are there any other stacks more relevant to this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As it is stated in the Help Center:

"We ask and answer questions about **electrical and electronics engineering topics**, which include electronics, physical computing, and those working with microcontrollers, Arduinos and embedded systems."

Control Systems is one the major areas of Electrical Engineering so they are welcome in this Q&A site.

Comment: I didn't realize our description specifially included arduinos. That needs to be fixed.  But otherwise, yes I agree that control system concepts are on-topic here.

Comment: @OlinLathrop ECE departments make heavy use of Arduinos and microcontrollers in general not only practically but also academically so it is logical to be in a Q&A site of Electrical Engineering. Most Electrical Engineers are working with them and a lot are studying them.

Comment: Surely "Arduinos" are already covered by "microcontrollers". It seems both redundant (a little like saying we talk about electronic components and resistors) and overly specific (why just Arduinos and not BeagleBones, Raspberry Pis, Teensys, etc ...)

Comment: @brhans I guess that the description just mentions some specifics so to guide the new users as to what questions are relevant and specifies Arduinos because they are widely used especially by hobbyists. All these topics that you mention are accepted. They are covered under the name "Electrical Engineering" they just couldn't specify in a title everything so they just mention the most "famous".

Comment: EE.SE is the place until a more specialised SE is opened. Arduino's should be asked about in their SE, same goes for DSP. But uC in general are welcome here since they don't have their own SE. So unless a SE opens specifically for a certain topic and it falls within the Electronics scope, one should feel free to post it.

Comment: @Mast yes I agree but if someone is a member of this community and has question about Arduinos embedded in a project there are plenty to help here. Generally is a little difficult for people changing communities and asking as every community is different. However if someone is working only with Arduino and has countless questions then yes I believe that he should join Arduino.SE. As the description here is "Electrical Engineering" I think that they are relevant. I don't think that the fragmentation of the term in countless SE sites (DSP, Arduino etc.) is for the best.

Comment: @Adam I agree the fragmentation is not necessarily for the best. However, it seems to be in the spirit of SE format.

Comment: @Mast yes I agree with that and I think that if someone is working **solemnly** with a specific technology that has its own community (for example with Arduinos) then he must join the other community.

Answer (score 4):

This is the place. Make sure you include an electrical component as an example, even if your question is about the math of control theory. Otherwise your question will attract instinctive close votes.

Comment: Shouldn't need the electrical component.  Let the close votes come, and let the mods fix it.

Comment: I don't expect a properly written control system question would get downvotes.  If it's all dense math not being tied back to reality, then it will probably just sit there.  Otherwise, we have gotten questions like that here before, and I don't remember objections.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I agree with your comment but for the part about the mods :) It's not really our business to counter close votes. In fact, I personally tend to refrain from closing/reopening, since as a mod it just needs my vote to be effective. The community should be mostly self-moderating.